# string replace <br /> to \n gives double breaks

Tags: php, str-replace

**Solution information:**

The nl2br function does not replace `\n` with `<br />` as I had expected but inserts a `<br />` before the `\n`.

From php.net:

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

---

**Original question:**

I'm replacing `<br />` elements with `\n` in PHP, this is my input:

```
Top spot!<br />
<br />
123456789 123456789 123456789
```

This is my code:

```
$commenttext = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $reviewdata['comment']);
```

But my output is:

```
Top spot!



123456789 123456789 123456789
```

Is there something I'm missing with using str_replace? I'm getting double the breaks returned after using it.

Comment: Seems fine to me. If your input is actually like you posted, there are alreay linebreaks (\n) behind the <br> tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show you. Your code before replacement:

```
Top spot!<br />\n<br />\n123456789 123456789 123456789
```

Your code after replacement:

```
Top spot!\n\n\n\n123456789 123456789 123456789
```

As you can see `<br />` was correctly replaced with new line.

Try to replace `<br />` tags with the new lines first:

```
$commenttext = str_replace("<br />\n", "\n", $reviewdata['comment']);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I fixed it by using that last bit of code you posted. It's weird tho, I first sanitize the input, then put it through `nl2br();` before saving it in the database. It seems like it changes `\n` to `<br />\n`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$text = 'top spot!<br />
<br />
123456789 123456789 123456789';

echo str_replace("<br />\n","\n",$text);

?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z10d-7xsb)

> OUTPUT

```
top spot! 123456789 123456789 123456789
```

Comment: Daniil was just a little bit quicker, but thank you for your answer!